# Use logger in custom classes in my console application with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-6.0

I have a console application, and I added logger builder as follows in `Program.cs`:

```
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
            .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
            .AddConsole();
    });
    ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
```

Now say I have many classes in the project and all want to use logger. How can I make it available to other classes?

For example, I have:

```
internal class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        //use logger here
        //logger.LogInformation("Calling Test");
    }
}
```

In certain kinds of projects such as Azure Functions, the logger is readily injected in the functions, is there a similar way I can do it in Console application?

Answer (score 0):

To inject stuff, classes need constructors that accept dependencies as their parameters. For instance:

```cs
public class Test
{
    private ILogger logger;
    public Test(ILogger<Test> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //use logger here
        logger.LogInformation("Calling Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do that only and expect it to work? adding a logger in the constructor did not help me right away. I read I need to define the class as a service.

Comment: @Lamar. Certainly, the DI Container is only able to inject dependencies into a class that it as well creates. That means that `Test` needs to be registered/added to the Container/ServiceCollection and needs to be either requested directly from the container, or otherwise injected into another class.